# Running jest with bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

I've been working with vuejs and [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) lately.
Decided to add unit testing to my project.

I'm not realy familiar with unit testing so I'm trying anything I could find to understand how it works.

***Login.specs.js***

```
import { shallowMount, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Login from '@/components/auth/Login.vue'

describe('Login.vue', () => {
  it('is a Vue instance', () => {
   const wrapper = mount(Login, {
    mocks: {
     $t: () => 'Connexion' // i18N
    }
   })
  const h2 = wrapper.find('h2')
  expect(h2.text()).toBe('Connexion')
 })
})
```

***Login.vue***

```
<b-row align-h="center">
 <b-col class="text-center">
  <h2>{{ $t('login.connection') }}</h2>
 </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Everything seems ok with the test.
But I got these wannings and could find a way to actualy fix it.

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

So I looked around and it seems like I need to add these child components to the father.

Here is the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout) for these components.

I'm also adding my config files (There're the same as the vue-cli 3 generates them)

***jest.congif.js***

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
  'js',
  'jsx',
  'json',
  'vue'
 ],
 transform: {
  '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
  '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest- transform-stub',
  '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
 },
 moduleNameMapper: {
  '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
 },
 snapshotSerializers: [
  'jest-serializer-vue'
 ],
 testPathIgnorePatterns: [ //I've added this one, not sure if usefull
  '<rootDir>/node_modules'
 ],
 testMatch: [
  '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're adding bootstrap vue as a global plugin:

```
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

Then in your tests, you're likely going to want to follow this tip:

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/common-tips.html#applying-global-plugins-and-mixins

Which outlines how you can use the `createLocalVue()` and set it up with the same global config as your app:

```
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

// create an extended `Vue` constructor
const localVue = createLocalVue()

// install plugins as normal
localVue.use(BootstrapVue)

// pass the `localVue` to the mount options
mount(Component, {
  localVue
})
```

Then your components should be registered properly-

Comment: It still displays warns `[BootstrapVue warn]: tooltip unable to find target element in document`

Comment: i am facing the same issue and even after installing BootstrapVue plugin globally  like this **localVue.use(BootstrapVue)**  test run prints the warning in console "Unknown custom element: <b-alert> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option." how to fix it? @BartusZak

Comment: It still displays warns for me. I did not find any solution :(

Comment: @BartusZak stubbing the bootstrap vue component on mount solves the issue .. there are not warning in the console.

Comment: Set `BOOTSTRAP_VUE_NO_WARN` to disable warnings.

Comment: @BartusZak I had the same issue and I also had to add `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` before `expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()`. Sometimes I needed to add more than one `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` so all the children rendered. See how bootstrap-vue does it: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/c3db7585ce6bc62c9b4ee50a934a471b185c94c9/src/directives/tooltip/tooltip.spec.js#L59

Comment: @BartusZak Also sometimes I had to add `attachTo: createContainer()` (same function as bootstrap-vue). that got rid of 99% of my tooltip warnings

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on [chrismarx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598621/11312528) answer.

Here is a example used in a `vue/nuxt` application with `bootstrap-vue`. While testing my component `FormInput.vue` that has some elements from `bootstrap-vue`, I was getting errors like `Unknown custom element: <b-form-input>` and `Unknown custom element: <b-col>` and `Unknown custom element: <b-row>`

[Doc](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#slots) show example for using slots and custom components. I did the following to move past my errors. Note the `bootstrap-vue` import and the `stubs` section:

```
import { /* mount, */ shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { BRow, BCol, BFormInput } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import FormInput from './FormInput.vue'

describe('FormInput test', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FormInput, {
      stubs: {
        // used to register custom components
        'b-form-input': BFormInput,
        'b-row': BRow,
        'b-col': BCol,
      },
    })
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Comment: Only the above solution worked for me. 
I've tried initially to use the `localVue()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to stub components like

```
const wrapper = mount(Login, {
  mocks: {
    $t: () => 'Connexion' // i18N
  },
  stubs: {
    BCol: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! It kinda worked, i had 64 "errors", only 40 remains, some of them are b-cols or b-rows. I'll look it up later.

Answer (score 1):

I see very inefficient import all components of boostrap-vue in each test.

You can add a file with all import and added into jest config file

**jest.config.js**

```
...
setupFiles: ['./jest/loadConfig.js'],
...
```

**loadConfig.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import GlobalComponents from './plugins/globalComponents';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(GlobalComponents);
```

and for end the plugin for global components

**globalComponents.js**

```
import { BRow, BCol } from 'bootstrap-vue'

const GlobalComponents = {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.component('b-row', BRow);
    Vue.component('b-col', BCol);
  }
};

export default GlobalComponents;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this.
Firstly, If you use `localVue` instance you have to register your bootstrap-vue component as global object using this `localVue.component("b-breadcrumb", BBreadcrumb)`

> I will mention to `b-breadcrumb` as if it any part of boostrap-vue's components.

```js
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.component("b-breadcrumb", BBreadcrumb)
mount(CustomComponent, {
  // Some options
})
```

Secondly, If you don't use `localVue`instance you can register this component as a param of mount method like this

```js
mount(CustomComponent, {
  // Some options
  components: {
    BBreadcrumb
  },
})
```

> There is a important issue that If you use `localVue` instance components option of mount method will not work.

Also you can ignore any bootstrap-vue component to avoid unneccessary rendering using `stubs` option of mount method.

```js
mount(CustomComponent, {
  stubs: ["b-breadcrumb"]
})
```

More information about options of mount [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html)