# jest chai vuejs trigger('click') not working

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils, ts-jest

i try to create a simple test who :

- click on button
- show if dropdown is open

i try to simulate a click with trigger but it is not working,
do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?

```
    describe('test clique boutton filtre', () => {
  test('should show dropdown de la colonne 1', async (done) => {
    const dropdown = wrapper.find('#nom-divUpperDrop')
    const button = wrapper.find('#nom-dropdown')

    await button.trigger('click')

    expect(dropdown.findAll('.show').length).equal(1)
    done()
  })
})
```

i'am sure i find the button because the console log show  :

```
<button type="button" id="nom-dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-bs-haspopup="true" aria-bs-expanded="false" data-bs-offset="-60,10" data-bs-auto-close="outside" class="nav-icon clear-btn">
      <p> false </p>
    </button>
```

here the dropdown where i want to find the .show

```
> <div aria-labelledby="nom-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
>         <div>
>           <div class="filter-deroulant">
>             <!---->
>             <div class="filter-input">
>               <div class="input-group mb-3"><input type="text" id="filtre_0" value="" placeholder="Recherche par nom"
> aria-label="Rechercher" aria-describedby="nom" class="form-control col
> form-control-sm"> <button type="button" id="nom" class="btn
> btn-outline-secondary"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
> data-prefix="fas" data-icon="search" role="img"
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
> aria-expanded="false" class="svg-inline--fa fa-search fa-w-16">
>                     <path fill="currentColor" d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0
> 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4
> 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"
> class=""></path>
>                   </svg></button></div>
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>         <div>
```

Any idea?

ps: i tried this : [Vue Testing (JEST): button.trigger('click') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828904/vue-testing-jest-button-triggerclick-not-working)

ps: I tried the button manually, it's work :)

but it's not working for me

Comment: where exactly is the element `.show` that you are trying to find. I don't see it in your markup.

Comment: Bootstrap, after click gonna add .show on this line : <div aria-labelledby="nomdropdown" class="dropdown-menu HERE">

Comment: I'm not very familiar with bootstrap-vue, but I think `aria-labeledby` should match the `id` of the button, which in your case it doesn't. check if that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is not the problem, i just made a mistake when I copy/Paste